# Mysql xref table- add column or sparate

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

I have a cross reference table that contains three major columns:

- object id
- different object id
- relation type between the two

Problem is, on some cases I need two more columns that help define the relation between the two objects.

My question is, what is the proper way to deal with the situation?

Should I create another table with five columns, and have two table for practically the same purpose?
Or is it ok to add two more columns that will almost always contain null. Will it needlessly affect response time and size?

Thanks

**edit-**
 I've been asked for more information, so here it is:
the database hold philosophical arguments.
This specific table holds the information of which which statements are connected in what logic.
these are the columns:

- statement_id
- logic_id
- direction

which are good for two-way logic (such as 'if-then'); 
But in case of a multiple statement logic (such as 'and' or 'or') I needs two more columns:

- exit
- inner-logic type

I'm not sure if this extra information helpful or just more confusing. feel free to ignore it and answer the question on purely academic base.

Comment: Use foreign keys ?

Comment: Regardless of foreign keys, I have two more columns that give more details about the combination of the two objects together

Comment: Can you pls provide some examples of relationships where only 3 columns are needed and some examples when you may need 5? It is hard to understand the issue without something concrete.

Comment: My question is a more, best practice/ optimization question, so I didn't think it was necessary. But, I'll edit more information into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ok to have two ids and any number of columns describing the relationship.  Those extra columns could be `NULLable` if they are optional or whatever.

It sounds like the two ids `JOIN` to a single table, correct?  In that case, you may need to `UNION` two selects to check for an id in either of the columns.  And have multiple indexes, one starting with one id, one starting with the other.

It would help if you provided `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a `SELECT` or two.  That might give us a better feel for what the tables are for.